# Cannot convert string to DateTime

Tags: c#, linq

I want to get a max date from the List<>.

But I don't know how to convert `x.time` to DateTime.

It always show error like this in exception: 
`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`.

Here my code to do this:

```
List<DTOSaveFromFile> lst = Load();

public static List<DTOSaveFromFile> Load()
{
   string[] data = File.ReadAllLines(dataPath);
   return (from i in data select new DTOSaveFromFile(i)).ToList<DTOSaveFromFile>();
}

foreach (var rows in lst)
{
    DateTime biggest = lst
        Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.time, "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) //to get the list of `string` of `time` from your List<DTOSaveFromFile> + //To convert it to DateTime 
        .Max(); //Get the max among the DateTime
}
```

`x.time` from class:

```
public class DTOSaveFromFile
{
    public string reportName { get; set; }
    public string eMail { get; set; }
    public string time { get; set; }
}
```

How to resolve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: You might also want to post the value of x.time when the error occurs? Because the error might be caused by `x.time` not being a "clean" data. That means, among all the data you have, the `time` could be of different format.

Comment: `x.time` is:    x.time "05-01-2016" string

Comment: That's it! so you need to add that format!

Comment: Add like:
Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.time, "dd-MM-yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))

Comment: No, no `dd-MM-yyyy` cannot handle `6-1-2015`, it can only handle `06-01-2015`. Better to use single `d` and `M`

Comment: This link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx you might find it very useful.

Comment: That right. That worked for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100014/discussion-between-ian-and-fds).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the format for your `DateTime.ParseExact` to handle that `05-01-2016` case

```
string[] formats = new string[] {"d/M/yyyy", "d-M-yyyy"}; //notice the dash
```

Then your query would be like:

```
string[] formats = new string[] {"d/M/yyyy", "d-M-yyyy"}; //notice the dash
DateTime biggest = lst
        .Select(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.time, formats, //now use formats here
                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal)) //to get the list of `string` of `time` from your List<DTOSaveFromFile> + //To convert it to DateTime 
        .Max(); //Get the max among the DateTime
```

Note that there is additional parameters you may need to all in your `DateTime.ParseExact`, which is `System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal`.

Also, whenever you find an error due to new `format`, just add that `format` in the `formats` array